# CodeIgniter Team Work

Tags: php, codeigniter, workflow, collaboration

I've been learning CodeIngiter and up till now but can't seem to get a grasp on how CodeIgniter can be used to work as a team. Can someone explain the basic of team work using CodeIgniter?

From what I understand, it's like this so correct me if I'm wrong :

Let's say there is a project with 5 pages, Home, About Us, News, Gallery and Contact Us. Where CodeIgniter can help is let's say I have 2 programmers in my team, so each one of us do a module (for each Controller-View-Model) (for example Programmer A does News module, Programmer B does Gallery module) in different folders (folder news and gallery), etc.

So the end product will be a group of modules in seperate folders. home/ , content/, news/, gallery/, contact/ , etc.

Is that the right flow of teamwork using CI? I read that CI can be used to collaborate between designers (front end CSS) and programmers (database and controller) but I think with this flow, designers will have to wait for programmers to get the variable names to be parsed into the view and that will somehow halt the progress of the work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I currently work in a team environment with Codeigniter and I'll tell you generally it flows like this.

- Designer produces Designs coded out (html/css) with static content. (no variables)
- While he is doing that Myself and others are working on the data model we are going to use and writing Model Methods we can forsee needing to interact with the data in a way our application will utilize.
- Then the Designer hands off the static layouts, I "cut them up" into header/footer/etc... and replace the static content with the variables by writing the controllers to accomodate.

**As a bonus** I would ***highly*** recommend using some sort of version control with your team, depending on your needs I usually stick with [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/) or [GIT](http://git-scm.com/),  GIT is a little more accommodating to distributed teams that are not in a centralized location.  This will greatly improve efficiency and prevent ( or mitigate ) situations in which two people end up working on the same file and someones work gets overwritten, and other situations that occur when multiple people are working on the same files.

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter is just one way of doing of [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller). You probably don't need to divide things up into separate modules or folders; instead, you'll probably want to create files like this:

**controllers/gallery.php

controllers/home.php

controllers/news.php**

**views/gallery_view.php

views/home_view.php

views/news_view.php**

**models/page.php

models/picture.php**

It's perfectly legal for each controller to make use of multiple models and views; in fact, that's the point. A blog controller might use models for user, post, and comments. You can also do sub-views which are used from inside your other views (such as views/header_view.php).

If your project has well-defined specs, you might consider making the team division between one person doing the model and controller logic, and another writing the view output. Or, you could divide the work between different pieces of the site; however, you'll still want to write some shared code that gets used project-wide. That's the biggest principle of MVC: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: so basically, the team needs to cooperate to write some functions that may need to be used project-wide then for each other pieces, they work independently, right?

Comment: @Henson: As Luke said, the advantage is given by the MVC sepparation, so developers can work in M-C part and make a basic View that can be _later_ polished by designers.

Comment: while the DRY principle is a staple of programming in general, i do not see how it directly relates to MVC, especially to be considered the **Biggest Principle**.  I would say that would be logic separation, specifically for MVC models.